# Having difficulty installing TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Keep getting this error message:

```
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Are those errors from _installing_ it?  If so, what is the command you used to start the install?

Comment: Here is the command:
conda create --name py3-TF2.0 python-3
conda activate py3-TF2.0
(py3-TF2.0) C:\Users\HP>conda install tensorflow
(py3-TF2.0) C:\Users\HP>pip install --upgrade tensorflow
(py3-TF2.0) C:\Users\HP>python
>>> import tensorflow